# display time on the screen with a nice format

Tags: c++, time, formatting

```
void clock(int hour, int minute){   
wstringstream wss;
time_t second;
struct tm *current;
current = localtime(&second); // get the running time which is in ms
second = clock()/1000-extra;  //now convert it to second, "extra" is 0 in the start
char buffer[80];

if (second == 60){ 
    setminute(clock() / 1000 / 60);
    i=1;
    extra=extra + 60*(i); 
   //when 60 passed, second will return to 0, i start at 0 in somewhere else;
}
else if (startminute == 60){ sethour(clock() / 1000 / 60 / 60); setminute(0); }

wss << starthour  << " : ";
wss << startminute << " : ";
wss << second << " ";
wss << "AM" << endl;


textToGenerate.append(wss.str());
}
```

This is how i convert program running time to hour minute second format. I set clock start at 12:00am. and it looks like this `12 : 0 : 0 am` on the screen

I am wondering if there is anyway i can change the format to standard `00:00:00` am/pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strftime with r%. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/